# Kubuntu 20.04 won't wake from suspend Nvidia

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, kubuntu, suspend

I don't have this problem on other flavors, but on Kubuntu 20.04 when my desktop goes to suspend it won't wake up. My keyboard is still lit up and and everything working, but moving the mouse or using the keyboard won't wake it from suspend. I have a dual monitor setup if that's relevant. Will provide more information and command outputs if needed.

I'm using Nvidia driver 470.86 and this is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Lenovo Group Limited LEN L24q-30"
    HorizSync       114.0 - 114.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "On"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +2560+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```